# How to set a asp:DropDownList SelectedValue to a Session Variable?

Tags: asp.net, session, drop-down-menu, session-variables, sqldatasource

There are several articles describing how to do this is code behind however:

### Is it possible to set the value of a dropdownlist to a session variable on the aspx page?

I am using SqlDataSource to populate the dropdownlist so do not wish to add code behind if it can be avoided.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="Server" DataSourceID="sqlDS" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="TEXT" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="True" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDS" runat="Server" SelectCommand="spDS" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />
```

Set **Session("ID")** as selected value on load?

---

The dropdown list is already populated from the sqldatasource. I just want to set the initial value on page load.

Comment: You can take the "code behind" and embed it into your ASPX page into `<% %>` blocks, but what's the point?

Comment: Good point. Mainly so the complete dropdowncode is in one code block and not on both pages. Quick move and delete later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a server side code in order to use **Session**. The following code doesn't requires code behind file, but again the code inside **script** will run at **server side**.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="Server" 
   DataSourceID="sqlDS" 
   DataValueField="ID" 
   DataTextField="TEXT" 
   AppendDataBoundItems="true"
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" 
   AutoPostBack="True">
  <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Selected="True" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDS" runat="Server" 
  SelectCommand="spDS" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />

<script runat="server">
    protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["SelecteValue"] = ddl.SelectedValue;
    }
</script>
```

**Note:** Make sure `AutoPostBack="True"` for DropDownList.

Comment: Is it not possible to do something like <% session("ID") %>. My ddl is inside a repeated making code behind excessive markup.

Comment: `<% %>` is a server side code. You cannot use **Session** at client side.

Comment: The dropdown list is already populated from the sqldatasource and is nested in a repeater. I just want to set the initial value once on page load.

Comment: @DreamTeK Your comment is totally different from the original question. Could you please create a new question and post your code with **repeater control** *(so that we know where you get stuck)*?

Comment: Agreed. The answer to this question is NO unless using the technique described in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix code with markup. It makes sense to separate them for many reasons. So ASPX will have just the presentation, and CS/VB just the code logic.

When you compile/deploy your side to production - there will not be "the second page" - only ASPX page will remain. Code will be compiled into a DLL.

Comment: I agree with the separation of presentation and code, but this does not answer OP's question.  Also compiling is optional (while more secure) makes deploying changes later more difficult.  Can still separate code and presentation and not compile.  Just my $0.02

Comment: @Feuerwehrmann I did provide answer in my initial comments - embedding the server-side code inside of ASPX page. But sometimes alternative answer may serve a better purpose if it leads to OP rethinking the the original request

Comment: sorry missed that.  You are correct though much better to keep display and logic apart

Answer (score 0):

you'll need an event for your dropdown list on change.  Are you using C# or VB.net for your codebehind?

add to  onSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged"

to your code behind add:

{this is C# vb is similar}

```
protected void ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["selectedID"] = ddl.selectedValue;
}
```

to your page load, add

```
if (isPostback)
{
    ddl.selectedValue = Session["selectedID"];
}
```

Comment: VB please. The dropdown list is already populated from the sqldatasource. I just want to set the initial value.

Comment: You won't need the property on the display code (<asp:DropDown ...)  add to your code behind protected sub ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) handles ddl.SelectedIndexChanged <br/> Session["selectedID"] = ddl.selectedValue <br/> end sub

Comment: <br/> are replaced with real new lines since enter submits the answer here

Comment: This will not set the value until the dropdownlist is change. I wish to set the initial value when the page loads.

Comment: add the same block of code to a DataBound event e.g. protected sub ddl_Databound(sender as object, e as eventargs) handles ddl.Databound <br/> Session("selectedID") = ddl.selectedValue<br/>end sub

Comment: i realize now that I read your question backwards.  You want the selected value of the dropdown list to be the value already stored in a session variable